# min-width on tags looks ugly in new meta.SE design

Tags: feature-request, design

> [image: screenshot]

Could the minimum width be removed from tags? It looks very ugly to see 90% blank box and 3 letters.

Comment: Jin is going to have a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: More annoying on [bug]; [even moreso on \[bug\] \[diff\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/229762/1).

Comment: I just realized that this completely screwed some of our defensive fortifications: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99598/238586

Comment: Also, font looks bad. And needs to be moved down 1px if it isn't changed.